Azure DevOps - Capacity Planning at Story Level
Can we do capacity planning in Azure Devops based on estimation at story or feature level? ADO currently allows capacity planning at task level only.
Can we configure the capacity planning other then the task level?

Azure DevOps currently allows capacity planning at the task level only. As a workaround, the most straightforward approach is to ensure that all tasks under a User Story or Feature are estimated. The aggregate of these task estimates can serve as an indirect capacity measure for the Story or Feature.

Currently, Azure DevOps only supports task-level capacity planning. If you want other level capacity planning, you can submit a feature request here. I noticed that there is already a similar feature request Capacity Planning using Story Points, you can follow it and add some comments to let the product team know your thoughts.
